# decorating an attribute in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a `name` attribute on a `Person` model and every time I access the `name` attribute, I want `name.capitalize` to be returned.

Doing the following inside the model won't work,

```
def name
  name.capitalize
end
```

so what is the alternative?

Answer (score 15):

I suggest you to create a secondary method with your custom formatters.

```
class Person

  def formatted_name
    name.capitalize
  end

end
```

This is a better solution compared with overwriting the default implementation because setter and getters might called when updating/writing/saving the record to the database.
I remember once when I overwrote the default implementation of an attribute and each time a record was saved, the attribute was updated with the formatted value.

If you want to follow this way you can use `alias_method_chain` or take advantage of inheritance including an external module.

```
class Person

  def name_with_formatter
    name_without_formatter.capitalize
  end
  alias_method_chain :name, :formatter

end
```

Also you can overwrite name and call `read_attribute(:name)` from within your custom method.

```
def name
  read_attribute(:name).capitalize
end

def name
  self[:name].capitalize
end
```

Again, don't do this. Go ahead and create a custom method.

Comment: Why don't you recommend your last suggestion?

def name
  self[:name].capitalize
end

Looks elegant, it is just a attribute reader. What's the problem?

Comment: Mostly because some plugins relies on name, some other calls self[:name]. You might end up with inconsistent values.

Comment: There is a problem with method chaining in active record http://onehub.com/blog/posts/decorating-activerecord-accessor-methods/

Answer (score 2):

But happens when name is null?

capitalize will throw an undefined method for nil::Class if self[:name] returns nil.

The following covers that:

```
def name
  self[:name] ? self[:name].capitalize : nil
end
```

But I agree that you should create the formatted method and leave the name method as is. Never know when you might need the raw data.

FYI: the reason why your method didn't work was because it was causing, what I like to call, a self referring loop. You are redefining the method but calling the method in the new method. So you have to use `self[:name]` or `read_attribute` to get to the internal model data.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
def name
  self[:name].capitalize
end
```