# Can I implement rails setter and getter for attributes for db columns

Tags: ruby-on-rails, setter, getter

In rails we can access db column through attributes rails provided, but can we change this ?
for example I have db with name column could I implement something like.

```
def name
  "sir" + name
end
```

I tried it, but it result in stack overflow. There is a way to accomplish this.

more question, Is there any difference between name and self.name.

Comment: Resulted in StackOverflow indeed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
def name
  "sir" + read_attribute(:name)
end
```

But avoid this practice. Use an additional getter/setter instead, also known as "virtual attribute".
For more information read this answer: [decorating an attribute in rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1144039/decorating-an-attribute-in-rails/1144082#1144082)

In your case, there's also a weird side effect. Each time the attribute is accessed, it appends the name. After 3 calls, you end up with

```
"sir sir sir name"
```

Indeed, you can do

```
def name
  n = read_attribute(:name)
  if /^sir/.match(name)
    n
  else
    "sir #{n}"
  end
end
```

but, seriously, don't do this.

Comment: I agree that adding a formatted_name method is the way to go, per the link. Don't mess with the attribute name, it's not worth it.

Answer (score 2):

If you're aware of the possible complications, but still need to do this, then:

```
def name
  "sir" + self[:name]
end
```

Comment: it is just short hand, see "Overwriting default accessors" at http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html

Answer (score 0):

Use `super`

[Ruby Overriding methods](http://rubylearning.com/satishtalim/ruby_overriding_methods.html)

It has a lot of explaining but I think it is as simple as calling the method that's already defined

```
def name
  "sir #{super}"
end
```